# avoid rerendering on multiple setState

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this case where I have to pull config from API, I do multiple setState in react useEffect.

like

```
setConfigPartA(data.a)
setConfigPartB(data.b)
```

I don't want to combine everything using useReducer because it might grow, and each config has different logic to bind to the UI. Any tip? does it make sense to memoize the data? I'm not sure what's the drawback.

Comment: There are ways around this, like just having one state object with everything in it, or using `unstable_batchedUpdates` from `react-dom` to force batching of state changes. But honestly re-rendering shouldn't be a big deal. If 2 renders instead of 1 is causing performance issues then the problem is likely not so much the 2 re-renders, it's that your component isn't efficiently designed and a render cycle is too 
heavy. The solution to *that*  varies greatly, depending on what the actual cause of the problem is

Comment: Calling the setter returned from [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) "enqueues a re-render of the component," and React may batch renders; there's no guarantee a `setConfigPartA` and `setConfigPartB` will necessarily mean two renders. That being said, @Jayce444 makes good points: don't worry about this until you've measured and proven that these renders are actually a performance bottleneck. If rendering this component is truly expensive, post the component for feedback on how to improve it.

Comment: it's so scary when I see 5 log upon landed on the page